# Change NumberFormat (with expression) in array

Tags: excel, vba, number-formatting

I want to use an expression to change the format number of an array:

```
'ArrayTOService(i) = Format(ArrayTOService(i), "[>=1000000] $#,##0.0,,""M"";[>0] $#,##0.0,""K"";General")
ArrayTOService(i).NumberFormat = "[>=1000000] $#,##0.0,,""M"";[>0] $#,##0.0,""K"";General"
```

I have tried these two solutions. None of them working.

Comment: in the first solution i would like to use NumberFormat instead of the Format function, but VBA doesn't allow me. Don't know why. The problem of this solution is that i don't get numbers but strings

Comment: Is `ArrayTOService(i)` an internal VBA array or an array of worksheet cells ???

Comment: just an array that i made up. i use it for some graphs.

Answer (score 0):

If
    `ArrayTOService`

is just a VBA array, you do not need a qualifier:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim ArrayTOService(1 To 2) As String
    For i = 1 To 2
        ArrayTOService(i) = "[>=1000000] $#,##0.0,,""M"";[>0] $#,##0.0,""K"";General"
    Next i
End Sub
```

**EDIT#1:**

We need to convert each **numeric** value into a **string**:

```
Sub dural2()
    Dim ArrayTOService(1 To 2) As String
    ArrayTOService(1) = 1.123
    ArrayTOService(2) = -8.123

    For i = 1 To 2
        ArrayTOService(i) = Format(ArrayTOService(i), "[>=1000000] $#,##0.0,,""M"";[>0] $#,##0.0,""K"";General")
    Next i

    MsgBox ArrayTOService(1) & vbCrLf & ArrayTOService(2)
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: I am sorry, but i don't get you. Your code writes as string the number format. It erases actually the values of arrayToService(i)

Comment: Please some help?

I have found that the function FORMAT just works in Excel, not with arrays. How can I change the formatnumber in a array? I have 800000 and i want 800.000.

Comment: @Albert  see my **EDIT#1**

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, but still not what I need. I repeat, I don't want strings, I want doubles with points (800  .   000) in my array. 
I just want to have an array with doubles, and this doubles with the point separator for 1000- Ex: 1.000.000 instead of 1000000
Thanks!

Comment: @Albert  I don't understand.

Comment: I have an array with following info:
MyArray(1) = 800000 --> type Double / 
I want an array with following info:
MyArray(1) = 800.000 --> Type Double / your solution: MyArray(1) = 800.000 --> Type STRING.
 I don't want strings, I want doubles as type. I need to still operate with the numbers, i can't operate with strings, at least with charts